# Include dcmtk header files after WSL ubuntu installation using apt-get install

Tags: dcmtk

this is a silly question, but I'm having trouble including DCMTK to use in a script after installing it on Ubuntu running on a windows computer using the WSL platform.

SOLUTION:  I had a lot of trouble installing dcmtk and using the headers.  It turned out `apt install` was not installing the header files. Installing from source was throwing compiler errors. I installed homebrew and was able to get it to work that way.

I was then able to include header files as you'd expect with:

`#include "dcmtk/module/filename.h"`

Comment: Which Ubuntu package did you install? E.g., Debian has a libdcmtk-dev package, which includes the header files.

Comment: I was using just the `apt-get install dcmtk` I didn't know about the libdcmtk-dev options, that may have saved me a lot of time if I had.  My Ubunutu install is 20.04 from the Microsfot app store running on the Windows Subsystem for Linux

Comment: Header and library files are typically made available through the libxxx-dev package. There is nothing special about it for the dcmtk package.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware of this